# jQuery keyup working incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, keyup, reverting

I am trying to make an integer variable increment every time the Enter key is pressed. This variable is then used to output a value from an array.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                console.log(++currSteps);
                $('#output').text(outNum[currSteps])
                if(outNum[currSteps] % 2 == 0){
                    $('body').css("background", "#4b84e5")
                }
                else if(outNum[currSteps] == 1){
                    $('body').css("background", "#9dd622")
                }
                else{
                    $('body').css("background", "#d16323")
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem occurs when I actually press Enter. On the first press, it works properly, and increments the variable `currSteps` and displays the next value in the array. However, when I press Enter again, it reverts it back to the original value of `currStep`, as long as Enter is held down, it will display the original value.

Now, yes, this event is for `keyup`, therefore it makes sense that things will work oddly on `keydown`. However... if I open up the developer tools and click around in the console, and then return to my original window, the `keyup` code works perfectly. Why is this only working after the developer tools have been opened?

I have tried this on jQuery 1.11.1 and 1.10.2.

Edit: `currSteps` and `outNum` declarations.

```
$('#in').click(function(){
            $('#output').empty();
            $('#steps').empty();
            var steps = 0
            currSteps = 0
            var inNum = parseInt($('#input').val());
            var col = '#ffffff'
            outNum = []
            outNum.push(inNum)
 ...
```

Comment: And where did you declare `currSteps` ?

Comment: Show us your `currSteps` and `outNum` definition

Comment: This isn't in a form is it? That could reload your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I allowed to myself to write a little of your missing variables defition: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ub5fg/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currSteps = 0;
    var outNum = { 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2 };
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(++currSteps);
            $('#output').val(outNum[currSteps] + ' ' + currSteps)
            if(outNum[currSteps] % 2 == 0){
                $('body').css("background", "#4b84e5")
            }
            else if(outNum[currSteps] == 1){
                $('body').css("background", "#9dd622")
            }
            else{
                $('body').css("background", "#d16323")
            }
        }
    });    
});
```

Is you problem still actual with upper demo?

Comment: Looks like problem somewhere else in your `testing` or `initialization` code

Comment: Yes, it would appear to be so. I declared the two variables in `$(document).ready()` instead and it started working.